# give page user control over where condition

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Hi im new to php and have very little knowledge, in my where statement I have where Status='A' and z.zoneID=1, is there a way to give the page user control over the z.zoneID=1 so that they can change it to any zoneID that is available, maybe through a drop-down list?

```
////////Query & Data Display is here/////////

$q=mysql_query("select r.*, f.Functionname,  m.Managername, z.Zonename from requests as r  inner join functions as f on r.functionID = f.functionID inner join managers as m on r.managerID = m.managerID inner join zones as z on r.zoneID = z.zoneID where Status='A' and     z.zoneID=1 order by Functionname");


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Function</th>
<th>Manager</th>
</tr>"
;
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo"<b>Zone: $nt[Zonename]<br>Capacity: $nt[Zonecapacity]</b><br><br>";
echo "<tr><td>$nt[Functionname]</td><td>$nt[Managername]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
/////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Create a form based on the zoneID. Add a <Select> to it. and that should be done.

Comment: thanks!, but where would i put the form in that code?

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out...

```
if( isset($_POST['zoneid']) ){

    $zoneID = $_POST['zoneid'];
    //Your extra code or processing here.
}

$q=mysql_query("select r.*, f.Functionname,  m.Managername, z.Zonename from requests as r  inner join functions as f on r.functionID = f.functionID inner join managers as m on r.managerID = m.managerID inner join zones as z on r.zoneID = z.zoneID where Status='A' and     z.zoneID=1 order by Functionname");


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Function</th>
<th>Manager</th>
</tr>"
;

// Here we create a form
echo "<form method='post' >";
echo "<Search for ZoneID: <input type='number' name='zoneid' /><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='search' />";
echo "</form>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo"<b>Zone: ".$nt['Zonename']."<br>Capacity: ".$nt['Zonecapacity']."</b><br><br>";
echo "<tr><td>$nt[Functionname]</td><td>$nt[Managername]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```